# Send value to behid code.vb from confirmation box jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I want to make confirmation box in  my web with jquery. when I choose ok/cancel, it will send value to my vb. But i always get trouble with the result. Whatever i choose (ok/cancel) it will give me result 'You clicked NO!'.
My second trouble happen when I click the button it will fire onclick first. I want it to fire onClientClick before onClick.

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    function cekData() {
        var periode;
        periode = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTglAwal').value;

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "AjaxToolkit.asmx/CekPeriodeData",
            data: '{ tgl: "' + periode + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                onGenerateCA(r.d,periode);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert('Error xhr:' + xhr + ' status:' + status + ' error:' + error);
            }
        });
    }

    

    // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onGenerateCA(cek, periode) {
        if (cek == true) { ConfirmKetemuData(periode); }
        else { Confirm(); }
    }

    function Confirm() {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Apakah anda yakin untuk generate data ke CA?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Ok";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "Cancel";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }

    function ConfirmKetemuData(periode) {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";

        if (confirm("Data periode " + periode + " sudah ada. Apakah anda yakin untuk generate data ke CA?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Ok";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "Cancel";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
</script>
```

button

```
<td class="btn" width="1100">
      <asp:Button ID="btnGenerateCA" runat="server" OnClick="onConfirm" Text="Generate CA"  OnClientClick = "cekData()"/>
</td>
```

.Vb

```
Protected Sub OnConfirm(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim confirmValue As String = Request.Form("confirm_value")
    If confirmValue = "ok" Then
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "alert", "alert('You clicked YES!')", True)
    Else
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "alert", "alert('You clicked NO!')", True)
    End If
    
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

I change button to

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnGenerateCA" runat="server"  OnClientClick = "if (!cekData()) { return false;};" OnClick="OnConfirm" Text="Generate CA" />
```

This code make my program hit the onclientclick first, but after the confirmation box appear and i hit ok/cancel, it not take me to the .vb, so I can't access .vb. Please help me fix this problem. Thanks